# Oracle Forms Tab Detail

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am using Oracle Forms. I want to know how to determine which tab the user is on at run time.

For example: I have created four tabs in my canvas A,B,C,D. At run time, how do I get to know which tab is currently being accessed by the user?

Comment: I don't have Forms to test it but [this old solution from the OraFAQ forums](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/121832/) seems plausible.

Comment: Thanks Sir, The link is definitely helpful.However, can you please help me with a link/website where in I an find all the properties of a Tab,canvas and other Form objects?

Comment: The Forms Builder has a Help function which will provide all that.

Comment: Thanks again Sir

Answer (score 0):

With

> Get_Item_Property(:system.cursor_Item, ITEM_CANVAS)

you can get the canvas name of the item. This will return the name of the tab control page. If you use the following command with this name:

> GET_CANVAS_PROPERTY(canvas_name,TOPMOST_TAB_PAGE);

you will get the name of the tab that is activated at this moment

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: If this helped you, please accept this as an answer